# Passing “+” string to controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, controller

I am trying to pass a encrypted string via url to my MVC controller. But the problem is when I try to decrypt it fails because when ever inside my string any "+" comes up gets replaced for a blank space.

I send this string: `s+MlmVt`
But the controller it's receiving it like this: `s MlmVt`

Is there any way to pass string smoothly?

Comment: Try escape it with "\" or write instead "%2B" intead of "+": s%2BMlmVt

Comment: There are a number of different characters in a URL which must be escaped. There are various methods in .NET to do this, e.g. `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. `+` gets escaped as `%2B`

Comment: Encode the URL first, so the + will be replaced with %2B. Your controller method will decode it back to + when binding.

Comment: Apply url encoding to the querystring before sending and decode when you'll get it

Comment: Thanks, @canton7 it worked. I used `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters need encoding to be sent correctly. Try sending `s%2BMlmVt` as `%2B` is the encoding of +

You can use https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp to find the encodings of other special characters

Comment: Rather than hand-encoding each character, use a library call (as @canton7 noted in the comments on the question).

Comment: Maybe link to the .NET methods which will do URI escaping?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter or parameters into the body instead of the url.
You should change the GET method by POST method.

```
    [HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Method([FromBody] Parameters Parameters)
    {
    }
```

Use [FromBody] to read the parameters.

```
public class Parameters
{

    public string EncryptedValue { get; set; }

}
```